# WPF .NET Core 5.0 app - Publish to single file - not showing resources

Tags: wpf, resources, release, single-file

I saw in .NET 5.0 that you can publish app in single file which is something I was very keep to test and use for my app. My problem is that after I publish the app using the "Produce single file" option the .exe file generated does not include my resources.

[image]

First part is exe app from publish folder
Second part is the exe app from build release folder

All the images are svg images with Build Action - Resource
I also tried with Build Action - Embedded resource and Copy if newer, but I had no luck.

Any ideas how can I make my svg embedded into my exe file?

Comment: You need to set the build action to "Resource". Do not copy artifacts. Then reference the images using pack URIs. That's it. Release mode. Clean & Rebuild. Publish.

Comment: @BionicCode can you please be a bit more specific about pack URIs. I use this way to specify the image location  <RibbonGroup x:Name="ClipboardRibbonGroup" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Clipboard_Ribbon_Group}" LargeImageSource="{svgc:SvgImage Resources/HomeTab/Clipboard/page_copy.svg}"> where Resources/HomeTab/ClipBoard is the folder of the image. page_copy is set as Resource but I still don't see it in the publish folder.

Comment: If the resource is located in the same assembly as the referencing object: `"pack://application:,,,/Resources/HomeTab/Clipboard/page_copy.svg"`. If the resource is in a different assembly than the referencing object (e.g., the referenced assembly is named `Resources`): `"pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/Resources/HomeTab/Clipboard/page_copy.svg"`. See [Microsoft Docs: Resource File Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#resource-file-pack-uris).

Comment: Should be `LargeImageSource="{svgc:SvgImage pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/Resources/HomeTab/Clipboard/page_copy.svg}"`

Comment: If you have Photoshop AI (Illustrator) you can convert svg images to XAML for easier usage. You then have a simple ResourceDictionary with drawings that you can host in a Viewbox..

Comment: @BionicCode Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MC3041 Markup extensions require a single '=' between name and value, and a single ',' between constructor parameters and name/value pairs. The arguments ' pack://application:,,,/Resources/HomeTab/Clipboard/page_copy.svg}' are not valid. Line 69 Position 112. I will try to find a way to "escape" the , but for now no success.

Comment: Which library is the SvgImage extension from? Tge extension probably exposes a property you can set.

Comment: @BionicCode based on your comments I managed to find the solution. Indeed the problem was the way I set the Image Path. I posted the answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was based on BionicCode the path of the ImageSource

I had to change the code from

```
      <RibbonButton x:Name="CoppyPageButton" Label="{x:Static p:Resources.Page_Copy_Button}" LargeImageSource="{svgc:SvgImage Resources/HomeTab/Clipboard/page_copy.svg}"></RibbonButton>
```

To

```
<RibbonButton x:Name="CoppyPageButton" Label="{x:Static p:Resources.Page_Copy_Button}" LargeImageSource="{svgc:SvgImage Source='pack://application:,,,/Resources/HomeTab/Clipboard/page_copy.svg'}"></RibbonButton>
```

Note that in order for the path to work it needed the single quotation marks.